# Updating Transaction Currency On Form Doesn't Update Custom Money Currency Symbol

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm creating an empty shell of a lead on a custom web page, then redirecting the user to the newly created lead.  The TransactionCurrencyId on the lead is empty on load, and in the OnLoad event, JS is setting the TransactionCurrencyId, and then populating the custom Money field.  Upon setting the money field, the following alert is being thrown:

> A Currency is required if a value exists in a money field.  Select a
>   currency and try again.

Manually clearing the TransactionCurrencyId, and then re-selecting the TransactionCurrency allows the user to manually populate the value.

Shouldn't the Transaction Currency be set by default, and how do I set the TransactionCurrencyId in order to set the Custom Money Currency Symbol?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this be calling this on the custom Money attribute in the `onLoad`, before actually setting the value:

```
att.$2_2.setCurrencySymbol("$")
```

Of course this is unsupported and not an ideal solution...