# Adding Price Per Unit in Opportunity Product Dynamic CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We Have an issue in Adding a product to opportunity product form.From the outset it looks related to the currency field:  When putting any value in for Price Per Unit - a red circle with a white x displays the message "A currency is required if a value exists in a money field.  Select a Currency and Try again."
Actually the issue came when we are trying to navigate from Opportunity form to our Opportunity Product Form with the help of custom javascript. If we navigate to opportunity Product form as it was before by clicking subgrid of the Product items in Opportunity form. The error doesn't show.
[Here is My error of the Price Per Unit field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sTk7.jpg)

The kicker is that there is no currency on the 'product line items' form. My first approach was to add the currency field so that we can manually enter it - this resulted in the currency field showing (but with a grey Lock icon)

[Currency Field Added to Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpA3O.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

Opportunity Products should be created from the subgrid on Opportunity. As you also noticed, this works.

The reason for this is that the currency on the Opportunity Product is automatically set to the same currency as set on the Opportunity when you use the supported out-of-the-box way of creating Opportunity Products:

You simply press the plus-sign in the subgrid, choose *Existing Product*, and find the product. The Opportunity Product record is then automatically created, with pricing automatically populated from the Price List. There is thus no need to do any home built navigation with JavaScript, as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: [Updating Transaction Currency On Form Doesn't Update Custom Money Currency Symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35612299/227436).

I ended up defaulting the currency when I created the record, if you don't have that ability, you're welcome to try the unsupported js I give in my answer.